# SpaxeX employees on the droneship when the booster lands?

Tags: spacex, landing, booster, droneship

SpaceX is doing a great job in recovering the boosters from its rockets.

The Falcon Heavy has 3 boosters.  2 of which land at Cape Canaveral and 1 on a drone ship somewhere in the ocean.

Are there engineers or other employees on the drone ship when the booster lands on it? Maybe in some type of 'safe room'?

I'm talking about this bad boy:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they're on a [separate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_spaceport_drone_ship#Operation) ship (a [tug boat](https://www.spacexfleet.com/hollywood)) nearby. This tug tows the barge into position, then detaches so the barge can use its own motors for positioning and retreats to a safe distance for the landing.

Comment: +1 *Autonomous* spaceport drone ship

Comment: Actually, do we know how far away the tug/support-ship goes? I keep seeing "why don't they relay the live feed via the nearby manned ship?" questions elsewhere...